# strange space issue when adding Kal as subview

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, kal

There's too much black space between the Kalendar and the navigation bar. Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image: kalview]

I'm calling the code from ViewDidLoad of a ViewController that I have in my storyboard:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    KalViewController *calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:calendar.view];
}
```

I'm just learning to use Kal.  Maybe I'm going about incorporating it in the wrong way.  I sure do like using the storyboard to link up my views so my viewcontroller includes "Kal.h" and I instantiate as shown in the code above.  I tried to make the viewcontroller a subclass of KalViewController but that didn't work.

Maybe there's a more elegant way of incorporating Kal into a hierarchy of storyboarded view controllers?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Please email me

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following:

```
[[self navigationController] initWithRootViewController:calendar];
[[calendar navigationItem] setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

and it should do the trick. The second line is being used to hide the "Back" button that otherwise becomes visible, but for me it's a single screen app, you may or may not want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the exact same code as you initially did ACB, had the exact same problem but I also had included `[self addChildViewController:calendar];` after the creation of the calendar view.

What does this code do? `[self addChildViewController:calendar`];

I understand it "adds a child view controller" but what is REALLY going on.... and should I need this? Apparently not because you didn't, and I just compiled my code without it and there was no difference.

**Overall code:**

```
KalViewController *calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:calendar.view];

//[self addChildViewController:calendar];
```